# Is com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION deprecated?

Tags: android, android-intent, google-cloud-messaging

Short version: is the intent `com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION` still used at all or has it been completely deprecated by GCM?

Longer version: Google's `gcm-demo-client` declares this intent in its filter, however, if I follow the same procedure, I get a valid registration id when I call `gcm.register()` and *then*, my broadcast receiver receives an additional registration id because of the REGISTRATION filter, and this second registration id is bogus (I can't send any notification to it).

At this point, I'm considering removing the `REGISTRATION` filter (and keeping just `RECEIVE`) but I want to make sure I'm not missing something important in the protocol.

Comment: as far as I remember, it was deprecated at the end of 2012 at least

Comment: That's my suspicion too but the fact it's still present in the official Google demo makes me wonder how true this is. Also, the GCM registration approach doesn't handle the case where Google decides to send your app a new registration ID (this scenario is covered by having a broadcast receiver handle a REGISTRATION intent, as C2DM used to do).

Comment: I don't really think that you lose something if you call `gcm.register()` from code and remove `REGISTRATION` filter

Comment: of course unless that new registration ID is going to be sent frequently, and used extensively in your app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably looking at an older version of the official Google demo.
The [current version](http://code.google.com/p/gcm/source/browse/gcm-client/AndroidManifest.xml) doesn't use `com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION`, as you can see here:

```
    <receiver
        android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="com.google.android.gcm.demo.app" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: Indeed. I'm not sure how I ended up with an old one since I thought I got it from the very place you are pointing to. The new registration still doesn't allow to handle the case where Google changes your registration id behind your back since the GCM servers can now no longer notify your application about that, but I'm guessing they won't be doing that until the GCM approach can handle it. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You risk not receiving registration IDs for a small percentage of your users.

https://blog.pushbullet.com/2014/02/12/keeping-google-cloud-messaging-for-android-working-reliably-techincal-post/

> Lesson #2: Be ready for register to repeatedly fail on some devices
>   even though a working registration ID is created.
>
> This tip is rather bizarre and may no longer be relevant but I have no
>   way of confirming if the bug in GCM has been fixed so here it is.
>
> The bug goes like this: no matter how many times you call register, it
>   will always fail and throw an exception on some devices. Even though
>   register is throwing an exception, a working registration ID is being
>   created but not returned. To get this registration ID, add this
>   permission to your GCM BroadcastReceiver’s IntentFilter:

```
<action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
```

Gotta love GCM. =)

Answer (score 4):

Even for the latest GCM version (aka GCM 3) the official GCM documentation [warns about the need of this permission for push support on old devices](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client#manifest):

> If you want to support pre-4.4 KitKat devices, add the following action to the intent filter declaration for the receiver: `<action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />`