# Why am I getting intent.REGISTRATION with Google Cloud Messaging

Tags: java, android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have been trying to implement GCM into my Android app. However, after following tutorial http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html

I'm getting intent type REGISTRATION with extra "unregistered" although I would expect some data.
At the start of app I'm registering without problem and receive registration id which is send to my server. I also use amazon sns.

BroadcastReceiver and IntentService are in separate package inside my main package.

Manifest:

```
package="my.main.package">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.REGISTER" />

<uses-permission android:name="my.main.package.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<permission android:name="my.main.package.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<receiver
    android:name=".gcm.FDGcmBroadcastReceiver"
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.cd2m.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

        <category android:name="my.main.package" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<service android:name=".gcm.FDGcmIntentService"/>
```

Broadcast receiver:

```
public class FDGcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String TAG = "FDGcmBroadcastReceiver";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Log.i(TAG, "on receive, " + intent.getAction());

        // Explicitly specify that GcmIntentService will handle the intent
        ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(), FDGcmIntentService.class.getName());
        // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching
        startWakefulService(context, intent.setComponent(componentName));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eran's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22217601/is-com-google-android-c2dm-intent-registration-deprecated) answers your issue.

In step 2 of the GCM doc that you linked, `com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION` is not among the intent-filter actions to include in your Manifest file.

Comment: It seems that solved the problem. Although I re-wrote whole code connected to it. Thanks.