# Android, apk installation INSTALL_FAILED_POLICY_REJECTED_PERMISSION

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to install application using Android Studio, I manage to install other apps except this app, when I try to install it I get few errors within the Logcat following by `INSTALL_FAILED_POLICY_REJECTED_PERMISSION` alert, I'm not sure what error relates to the main problem(not able to install the app) but here they are:

2 times the following error:

```
com.example.appName has no certificates at entry AndroidManifest.xml; ignoring!
```

after that there are 2 times:

```
getAuthToken called with non existant account: myoldemail@gmail.com
Failed to get auth token: no such account
android.accounts.AuthenticatorException: no such account
```

And finally I get an alert with `INSTALL_FAILED_POLICY_REJECTED_PERMISSION`.

To be precise(there was an app with the same name long ago so it might make sense, but anyway clicking ok fail to install the apk):

```
Installation failed with message INSTALL_FAILED_POLICY_REJECTED_PERMISSION.
It is possible that this issue is resolved by uninstalling an existing version of the apk if it is present, and then re-installing.

WARNING: Uninstalling will remove the application data!

Do you want to uninstall the existing application?
```

**Edit:**

I **factory reset** the device, and btw, **it's an 4.4.4 Note 4 device** and same error, so it should be the app or something with the build.

Furthermore, I removed all my accounts, removed the email app, I did probably everything online but still, same error.

**Edit:**

First, it's working on emulators, now, here are some more details, the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.appName">


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.appName.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.appName.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <application
        android:name=".AppClass"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <!-- https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-Android/issues/39 -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.parse.push.gcm_sender_id"
            android:value="id:1057382563338" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />

        <activity
            android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
            android:label="AppName"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.RegistrationActivity"
            android:label="Registration"
            android:parentActivityName=".activities.MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <!-- The meta-data element is needed for versions lower than 4.1 -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".activities.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.TouActivity"
            android:label="Terms of use"
            android:parentActivityName=".activities.MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <!-- The meta-data element is needed for versions lower than 4.1 -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".activities.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.PPActivity"
            android:label="Privacy policy"
            android:parentActivityName=".activities.MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <!-- The meta-data element is needed for versions lower than 4.1 -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".activities.MainActivity" />
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".activities.DashboardActivity"
            android:label="Dashboard"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />

        <activity
            android:name=".activities.PassChangeActivity"
            android:label="Password change"
            android:parentActivityName=".activities.DashboardActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <!-- The meta-data element is needed for versions lower than 4.1 -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".activities.DashboardActivity" />
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=".gps.GpsLocationReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name=".utils.CustomPushReceiver"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
        <!-- This receiver calling PushService defined above -->
        <receiver
            android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <!-- Receive the actual message -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <!-- Receive the registration id, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22217601/is-com-google-android-c2dm-intent-registration-deprecated -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="com.example.appName" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

As for my dependencies:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.0'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.15.0'
compile 'com.parse:parsefacebookutils-v4-android:1.10.4@aar'
compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.13.1'
compile 'com.parse:parsetwitterutils-android:1.10.5'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.0'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
compile 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding:rxbinding-appcompat-v7:0.4.0'
```

`compileSdkVersion`+`targetSdkVersion` is set to 24 and `minSdkVersion` is set to 19

Comment: This means your device has an administrator level policy preventing installation in certain cases.

Comment: @GabeSechan Thanks for the comment, could you explain more, maybe with an answer, I don't really know what that means and how to remove or change this policy, I've looked online and couldn't find anything about that, maybe you can linked me somewhere?

Comment: Have you set a device admin or device owner?

Comment: https://support.google.com/work/android/answer/6294687?hl=en that?

Comment: That's device ownership, although it has some details wrong (you can set ownership at any time later, so long as you don't associate a gmail account)

Comment: @GabeSechan I want to ask why not google account, but, I really have no idea where this goes, is device ownership/admin will fix the problem?

Comment: They most likely are the problem.  Removing it should fix it

Comment: @GabeSechan as I updated my question, I don't think it's the device anymore, I removed all accounts and administrators, factory reset the device and same thing, any app related direction?

Comment: check the  device Settings>Security and check if Unknown Sources is checked, or try removing any  Exchange Email

Comment: @Arjunsaini about the Unknown Sources, I've run into it many times and checked, if you check my edits I already removed all my accounts + the email app.

Comment: what is the actual package name that you are using ? and is the installation problem only coming on one device or multiple devices ?

Comment: Once I faced similar issue and i moved all activities to the root package and that fixed my issue. Try to move acitivities.DashboardActivity -> .DashboardActivity similarly all activities Tell me if rhia work's ?thanks

Comment: @AnirudhaAgashe I've changed the name already, it's not the name, it's just a simple all lower case name, something like com.example.somename

Comment: @JawadZeb on of the most interesting thing I had to try but not working, thanks anyway ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I updated Android Studio and Gradle it's working, I assume it was Gradle(was v2.1.3 and now v2.2.0).

Btw, after I updated android studio I was requested(by the new android studio version) to download API 19(minSdkVersion) platform tools, I don't know if it's relates but just wanted to point that out.

**Edit:** after I checked with the old gradle version v2.1.3 the problem is back so it looks like the problem was gradle(v2.1.3), when upgraded to v2.2.0 there is no problem at all.

Answer (score 3):

First thing that comes to mind is a device admin application is on your phone. This is usually the case for phones used in enterprise setting. The app forces certain policies for your phone. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html

As you already removed all your (exchange) email, my next guess is could be a problem within your app. There are few libraries/tools out there that require developer phones to work properly. Would you be able to share your manifest or/and dependencies to give us a better picture of your app?

Comment: I edited my question with some more data as requested, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have Knox installed on the device? I had a similar issue and Samsung Knox was the reason why I was getting the rejection. After I disabled Knox, I was allowed to install the .apk.

Also, have you checked that you have 'Unknown Sources' allowed? I assume you do since you have been able to install other apps, but I am curious what it is set to.

Do you know if the .apk is properly signed and aligned and all that?

Comment: Ryan, about Knox, I don't have it, the `Unknown sources`, I've tried for some many times, and about the apk, I created a new keystore, using android studio I set the build settings to use this specific new keystore and same error.